# Right to accommodation in case of delayed flight, missing connecting flight

Tags: air-travel, eu, delays, passenger-rights

A non-EU-citizen booked on a flight from outside the EU with a connection in Istanbul continuing into Europe experiences a flight delay of several hours due to bad weather on the first flight, and therefore misses the connecting flight in Istanbul. The connecting flight is re-booked to a flight one day later (>eight hours later). Both flights were booked with and are operated by the same airline.

According to http://marker.to/io9PYL and http://marker.to/jUNFOu there should be accommodation, food and compensation, *unless the delay is due to bad weather*, in which case they are still supposed to provide *assistance*.

What are the passenger's rights regarding accommodation, food, and compensation then?

Comment: Turkey is not inside EU, if the person is in Istanbul the assistance in these situations are handled by turkish rules (but I don't know them)

Comment: "Both flights were booked with and are operated by the same airline" but in the same booking? That's very important

Comment: What was the nationality of the operating airline? That can affect what set of rules cover them on delays

Answer (score 1):

as Ivan said did you book both flights together because as specified [in an other post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7410/booking-flight-tickets-together-or-in-separate-parts) and also on [this](http://www.flightrights.ie/common-questions.24.html) website if it is not the case then it becomes your problem and you won't have any right to pretend to any kind of compensation:

> My connecting flights were booked separately. If my first flight is
>   cancelled am I entitled to a refund for my other flight(s)? No.
>   Bookings made separately are regarded as separate contracts and under
>   the terms of the Regulation a refund will only be due for the
>   cancelled flight. However if the bookings were all made with the same
>   air carrier you may receive a refund at their discretion.

Comment: Worth waiting for the clarification to find out if they actually did book with the same booking before answering...just in case.

Comment: Getting back to this late… it was one and the same booking. Accomodation was paid, but no compensation otherwise since Airline claimed delays were due to bad weather. This was not obvious or explained at the airport, therefore the confusion. Thanks everyone!